# How to rotate exifed image using java?

Tags: java, orientation, exif

Is there a way, using java, to rotate a dataurl encoded image ?
Some photos has some orientation exif feature, and i can't succed in disabling this orientation ? (saving as png, the image stay rotated in the wrong orientation).

Regards.

Comment: nb : i use imageio and twelvemonkeys for now